# For Loop Expression Syntax Wrong

Tags: c#, syntax, for-loop

What is wrong with the following for loop syntax the `crv` variable is an array and I want an increment of 2:

```
for(int i<0; i<crv.Count;i+2)
{
  //Code Here
}
```

My compiler only says `Semicolon expected` which is not a very useful feedback...

Comment: The last part needs to be an actual expression. `i += 2` or `i = i + 2` and the first part an assignment.

Comment: The compiler and debugger are tools you need to learn how to use. The compiler will complain syntax problems, the debugger will let you see the logic you have written.

Comment: @Oded the problem is that my compiler only said `Semicolon expected` which was not so useful...

Comment: It points you in the right direction. It tells you where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note: first **section is assignment** You can't use comparison as `int i<0;`, instead it should be `int i=0` or `int i = -10` or anything similar as required.

Also in the increment section, either assign the updated value back to `i`

```
    for(int i =0; i<crv.Count; i+=2)
    {
      //Code Here
    }
```

or do the same in the body (just mentioning the option, which is useful in some specific scenarios)

```
    for(int i =0; i<crv.Count;)
    {
      //Code Here
      i+=2;
    }
```

Comment: Your/his first statement is wrong as well.  Also, there's nothing wrong with incrementing `i` by two in the `for` loop.  Moving it to the body only hurts readability, and adds nothing.

Comment: You now update `i` both in the `for` loop and in the body, that will increase it by 4 each iteration.

Comment: @Servy: Yup, I wrote the description correctly but made a mistake in copy. Updated the answer. `There was an issue as OP was not assigning the incremented value bac to i`. I just mentioned the option.

Answer (score 4):

You need to start out initializing `i` to zero, not comparing it to zero.  Additionally your last statement doesn't actually change `i`, it just returns a value of `i+2` and does nothing with that value, you need to actually set `i` to that result.

```
for(int i = 0; i < crv.Count;i+=2)
{
    //Code Here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The biggest error is that `i+2` is not reassigned to `i`.

```
for(int i = 0; i<crv.Count;i = i+2)
{
  //Code Here
}
```

You are throwing away the increment and `i` never changes value.

Then, you are not initializing `i` but checking whether it is less than `0`.

Answer (score 1):

While most of these answers do tell you how to fix your code they don't tell you why it doesn't work which I think is important for you to understand.

a `for` loop consists of three parts, separated by semicolons.

`for(part1;part2;part3)`

`part1` is executed **only** once - when the execution of the loop first begins. (this is normally where you assign an initial value to your counter)

`part2` is then executed next, checking if its value is true or false.

If is true, then the body of the loop is executed

Then `part3` is executed, (as you're attempting to do) this is normally where you increment

Then `part2` is checked again, if its true, it goes through the process again, if its false it exists the loop

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the for loop decides on i's initial value. in your example, you have "<", which isn't a solid value. Try i=0 instead. also, the last part reads as i, in addition to 2, instead of adding two each iteration. try i+=2 instead.